# C# regular expression to match ANY character?

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I write the following string to a string variable, carriage return and all:

```
asdfasdfasdf
asdfas<test>asdfasdf

asdfasdf<test>asdfasdf
```

In Notepad2, I use this regular expression:

```
<test>.*<test>
```

It selects this text as expected:

```
<test>asdfasdf

asdfasdf<test>
```

However, when I do this in C#:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "<test>.*<test>", string.Empty);
```

It doesn't remove the string.  However, when I run this code on a string without any carriage returns, it does work.

So what I am looking for is a regex that will match ANY character, regardless whether or not it is a control code or a regular character.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You forgot to specify that the Regex operation (specifically, the `.` operator) should match **all** characters (not all characters **except** \n):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "<test>.*<test>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

All you needed to add was `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: Har!  You're right!  I'll mark your response as the answer in 10 minutes when stackoverflow allows it =P.

Answer (score 13):

Use single-line mode:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "<test>.*<test>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the carriage returns in the string, then do your match:

```
s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Then it should work as expected:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "<test>.*<test>", string.Empty);
```